# Listenable Parameter Animation of AnimateBuilder not accepting AnimationController

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Flutter Beginner here. I am using Tween with an AnimationController. And I'm trying to use animate() method.

### Error Says as follows

> The argument type 'AnimationController?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Listenable'

Code I have used

```
Animation<double>? containerSize;
AnimationController? animationController;
Duration animationDuration = Duration(microseconds: 270);
```

initState method:

```
    void initState(){
       super.initState();
       SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
       animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: animationDuration);
   }
```

Tween Method declared Inside the Widget:

```
containerSize = Tween<double>(begin: size.height * 0.1, end: defaultRegisterSize).animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController!, curve: Curves.linear));
```

AnimateBuiler inside the Scaffold->Body->stack->children

```
//Register container
          AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: animationController,
            builder: (context, child){
              return buildRegisterContainer();
            },
          )
```

Calling at the Inkwell->GestureDetector

```
GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){
            animationController?.forward();

            setState(() {
              isLogin = !isLogin;  
            });
          }
```

How to assign AnimationController to the animation parameter of AnimateBuilder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `!` to make it non-null like so:

```
  AnimatedBuilder(
    animation: animationController!,
    builder: (context, child){
       return buildRegisterContainer();
    },
  )
```